# Bully Algorithm

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, network-programming, distributed-computing

Does anyone know if it is possible to find a working implementation of the [Bully algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_algorithm) in C# or Java somewhere?

The pseudo code in the articles I have found is terrible.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210516/suspicious-code-output-for-bully-algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another java version here I think

http://en.pudn.com/downloads111/sourcecode/internet/detail458790_en.html

Comment: Thank you for the link! It was definitely what I needed. I apologize for not stating from the beginning that I needed the processes to be running in separate address spaces.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.scribd.com/doc/6919757/BULLY-ALGORITHM) paper gives a pretty good rundown and has a java version at the end.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation in C#:

https://github.com/benaston/taskr

Disclaimer: I maintain it.