# Suspicious Code output for Bully Algorithm

Tags: java

I am writing a program for Bully Algorithm in Java
Here is the code:

```
package newbully;

public class NewBully {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total_processes = 6;
        RunningThread[] t = new RunningThread[total_processes];
        for (int i = 0; i < total_processes; i++) {
            t[i] = new RunningThread(new Process(i+1, i+1), total_processes);//passing process id, priority, total no. of processes to running thread
        }
        try {
            Election.initialElection(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Possibly you are using null references in array");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < total_processes; i++) {
            new Thread(t[i]).start();//start every thread
        }
    }
}


package newbully;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RunningThread implements Runnable {

    private Process process;
    private int total_processes;
    ServerSocket[] sock;
    Random r;

    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void setProcess(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public RunningThread(Process process, int total_processes) {
        this.process = process;
        this.total_processes = total_processes;
        this.r = new Random();
        this.sock = new ServerSocket[total_processes];
    }

    synchronized private void recovery() {
        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: -> Recovered from Crash");
        //Find current co-ordinator.
    }

    synchronized private void pingCoOrdinator() {
        try {
            if (Election.isPingFlag()) {
                synchronized (Election.lock) {
                    Election.lock.wait();
                }
            }
            if (!Election.isElectionFlag()) {
                Election.setPingFlag(true);
                System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: Are you alive?");
                Socket outgoing = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
                outgoing.close();
                Election.setPingFlag(false);
                synchronized (Election.lock) {
                    Election.lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Initiate Election
            System.out.println("process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: -> Co-Ordinator is down\nInitiating Election");
            Election.setElectionFlag(true);
            Election.setPingFlag(false);
            synchronized (Election.lock) {
                Election.lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized private void executeJob() {
        int temp = r.nextInt(20);
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(700);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Executing Thread:" + process.getPid());
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized private boolean sendMessage() {
        boolean response = false;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            if (Election.isMessageFlag()) {
                synchronized (Election.lock) {
                    Election.lock.wait();
                }
            }
            Election.setMessageFlag(true);
            if (Election.isElectionFlag()) {
                for (i = this.process.getPid() + 1; i <= this.total_processes; i++) {
                    try {
                        Socket electionMessage = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 10000 + i);
                        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "] -> Process[" + i + "]  responded to election message successfully");
                        electionMessage.close();
                        response = true;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "] -> Process[" + i + "] did not respond to election message");
                    }
                }
            }
            Election.setMessageFlag(false);
            synchronized (Election.lock) {
                Election.lock.notifyAll();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            System.out.println(ex1.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

    synchronized private void serve() {
        try {
            //service counter
            Socket incoming = null;
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(12345);
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
                incoming = s.accept();
                System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]:Yes");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(incoming.getInputStream());
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(), true);
                if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    if (scan.nextLine().equals("Who is the co-ordinator?")) {
                        System.out.print("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]:");
                        out.println(this.process);
                    }
                }
            }
            //after serving 10 requests go down for random time
            this.process.setCoOrdinatorFlag(false);
            this.process.setDownflag(true);
            try {
                incoming.close();
                s.close();
                sock[this.process.getPid() - 1].close();
                Thread.sleep((this.r.nextInt(10) + 1) * 1000000);//going down
                recovery();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sock[this.process.getPid() - 1] = new ServerSocket(10000 + this.process.getPid());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        while (true) {
            if (process.isCoOrdinatorFlag()) {
                //serve other processes
                serve();
            } else {
                while (true) {
                    //Execute some task
                    executeJob();

                    //Ping the co-ordinator
                    pingCoOrdinator();

                    if (Election.isElectionFlag()) {
                        if (!sendMessage()) {//elect self as co-ordinator
                            System.out.println("New Co-Ordinator: Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]");
                            this.process.setCoOrdinatorFlag(true);
                            Election.setElectionFlag(false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

package newbully;

public class Election {

    private static boolean pingFlag = false;
    private static boolean electionFlag = false;
    private static boolean messageFlag = false;
    public static final Object lock = new Object(); 

    public static boolean isMessageFlag() {
        return messageFlag;
    }

    public static void setMessageFlag(boolean messageFlag) {
        Election.messageFlag = messageFlag;
    }

    public static boolean isPingFlag() {
        return pingFlag;
    }

    public static void setPingFlag(boolean pingFlag) {
        Election.pingFlag = pingFlag;
    }

    public static boolean isElectionFlag() {
        return electionFlag;
    }

    public static void setElectionFlag(boolean electionFlag) {
        Election.electionFlag = electionFlag;
    }

    public static void initialElection(RunningThread[] t) {
        Process temp = new Process(-1, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            if (temp.getPriority() < t[i].getProcess().getPriority()) {
                temp = t[i].getProcess();
            }
        }
        t[temp.pid - 1].getProcess().CoOrdinatorFlag = true;
    }
}

package newbully;

public class Process {

    int pid;
    boolean downflag,CoOrdinatorFlag;

    public boolean isCoOrdinatorFlag() {
        return CoOrdinatorFlag;
    }

    public void setCoOrdinatorFlag(boolean isCoOrdinator) {
        this.CoOrdinatorFlag = isCoOrdinator;
    }
    int priority;

    public boolean isDownflag() {
        return downflag;
    }

    public void setDownflag(boolean downflag) {
        this.downflag = downflag;
    }

    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Process() {
    }

    public Process(int pid, int priority) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.downflag = false;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.CoOrdinatorFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
//--When delay in executeJob() method is 100

Process[4]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[4]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[5]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[4]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[5]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
process[1]: -> Co-Ordinator is down
Initiating Election
Process[1] -> Process[2]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[3]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[5]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
Process[2] -> Process[3]  responded to election message successfully
Process[3] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[4] -> Process[5]  responded to election message successfully
Process[2] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[2] -> Process[5]  responded to election message successfully
Process[3] -> Process[5]  responded to election message successfully
Process[5] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
New Co-Ordinator: Process[5]
New Co-Ordinator: Process[1]
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Address already in use: JVM_Bind


 //--When delay in executeJob() method is 700
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[5]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[6]:Yes
Process[5]: Are you alive?
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[6]:Yes
Process[4]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[6]:Yes
Process[4]: Are you alive?
process[4]: -> Co-Ordinator is down
Initiating Election
Process[4] -> Process[5]  responded to election message successfully
Process[4] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
Process[5] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
New Co-Ordinator: Process[5]
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[4]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[4]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[5]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
process[2]: -> Co-Ordinator is down
Initiating Election
Process[2] -> Process[3]  responded to election message successfully
Process[2] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[2] -> Process[5] did not respond to election message
Process[2] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
Process[3] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[3] -> Process[5] did not respond to election message
Process[3] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
Process[1] -> Process[2]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[3]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[1] -> Process[5] did not respond to election message
Process[1] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
Process[2] -> Process[3]  responded to election message successfully
Process[2] -> Process[4]  responded to election message successfully
Process[2] -> Process[5] did not respond to election message
Process[2] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
Process[4] -> Process[5] did not respond to election message
Process[4] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
New Co-Ordinator: Process[4]
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[2]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[1]: Are you alive?
Process[4]:Yes
Process[3]: Are you alive?
process[3]: -> Co-Ordinator is down
Initiating Election
Process[3] -> Process[4] did not respond to election message
Process[3] -> Process[5] did not respond to election message
Process[3] -> Process[6] did not respond to election message
New Co-Ordinator: Process[3]
New Co-Ordinator: Process[2]
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Finally I start getting exception of `Address already in use: JVM_Bin`.
Also if we check with the latest elected co-ordinator in ouput just before thowing exception it elects twice before asking `is co-ordinator alive?`
I am sure that when a co-ordinator dies I have provided enough delay to it so that it wont wake-up in between.
When I give extra dealy then program goes ahead else it stops in the middle.
Then why this problem must be occuring?

I found the reason for the exception
It is happening because if u look closely in output just before the exception message it has elected the co-ordinator 2ce.
Whenever a Thread is elected as co-ordinator it opens a ServerSocket at port 12345.
Since it happened 2ce it might be throwing exception.
But I dont get it... why did it elect the 2ce??

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Possibly you are using null references in array");` Then why don't you check for null references or catch a NullPointerException so you really know what the exception is?

Comment: @Ozzy: The exception never occurs on that line.
I have cross-checked that. That line I wrote because I should not accidently give any null references in the RunningThread array

Comment: Replace it with e.printStackTrace() so that you know what the actual exception is. Fix the code so that it does not do anything that causes an NPE. You should almost never supress exceptions like that. It makes bugs very difficult to find.

Comment: 1st thing I am not getting any NULLPointerAcception
secnodly sometimes only my code gives exception. sometimes it runs correctly. If u try executing it then u will find that sometimes it works fine. I wanted to ask why this is happening.
Thats why I gave 2 types of output.

Comment: @NileshBarai - you should fix it ... whether or not you are getting that message right now.  It is BAD CODE.  You shouldn't do stuff like that.  Not ever.  And fix all of the other places where you are catching `Exception`, because they will hide problems as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refering to all the above comments I am posting the corrected code which perfectly so others can refer it.
Any improvements suggestion in the code are welcome...

```
package newbully;

public class NewBully {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total_processes = 6;
        RunningThread[] t = new RunningThread[total_processes];
        for (int i = 0; i < total_processes; i++) {
            t[i] = new RunningThread(new Process(i+1, i+1), total_processes);//passing process id, priority, total no. of processes to running thread
        }
        try {
            Election.initialElection(t);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < total_processes; i++) {
            new Thread(t[i]).start();//start every thread
        }
    }
}

package newbully;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Election {

    public static ReentrantLock pingLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static ReentrantLock electionLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static boolean electionFlag = false; //By default no election is going on
    private static boolean pingFlag = true; //By default I am allowed to ping 
    public static Process electionDetector;

    public static Process getElectionDetector() {
        return electionDetector;
    }

    public static void setElectionDetector(Process electionDetector) {
        Election.electionDetector = electionDetector;
    }

    public static boolean isPingFlag() {
        return pingFlag;
    }

    public static void setPingFlag(boolean pingFlag) {
        Election.pingFlag = pingFlag;
    }

    public static boolean isElectionFlag() {
        return electionFlag;
    }

    public static void setElectionFlag(boolean electionFlag) {
        Election.electionFlag = electionFlag;
    }

    public static void initialElection(RunningThread[] t) {
        Process temp = new Process(-1, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            if (temp.getPriority() < t[i].getProcess().getPriority()) {
                temp = t[i].getProcess();
            }
        }
        t[temp.pid - 1].getProcess().CoOrdinatorFlag = true;
    }
}

package newbully;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RunningThread implements Runnable {

    private Process process;
    private int total_processes;
    private static boolean messageFlag[];
    ServerSocket[] sock;
    Random r;

    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void setProcess(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public RunningThread(Process process, int total_processes) {
        this.process = process;
        this.total_processes = total_processes;
        this.r = new Random();
        this.sock = new ServerSocket[total_processes];
        RunningThread.messageFlag = new boolean[total_processes];
        for (int i = 0; i < total_processes; i++) {
            RunningThread.messageFlag[i] = false;
        }
    }

    synchronized private void recovery() {
        while (Election.isElectionFlag());//if election is going on then wait
        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: -> Recovered from Crash");
        //Find current co-ordinator.         
        try {
            Election.pingLock.lock();
            Election.setPingFlag(false);
            Socket outgoing = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(outgoing.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outgoing.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]:-> Who is the co-ordinator?");
            out.println("Who is the co-ordinator?");
            out.flush();
            String pid = scan.nextLine();
            String priority = scan.nextLine();
            if (this.process.getPriority() > Integer.parseInt(priority)) { //Bully Condition
                out.println("Resign");
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: Resign -> Process[" + pid + "]");
                String resignStatus = scan.nextLine();
                if (resignStatus.equals("Successfully Resigned")) {
                    this.process.setCoOrdinatorFlag(true);
                    sock[this.process.getPid() - 1] = new ServerSocket(10000 + this.process.getPid());
                    System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: -> Bullyed current co-ordinator Process[" + pid + "]");
                }
            } else {
                out.println("Don't Resign");
                out.flush();
            }
            Election.pingLock.unlock();
            return;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    synchronized private void pingCoOrdinator() {
        try {
            Election.pingLock.lock();
            if (Election.isPingFlag()) {
                System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: Are you alive?");
                Socket outgoing = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 12345);
                outgoing.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Election.setPingFlag(false);
            Election.setElectionFlag(true);
            Election.setElectionDetector(this.process);
            //Initiate Election
            System.out.println("process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: -> Co-Ordinator is down\n" + "process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]: ->Initiating Election");
        } finally {
            Election.pingLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void executeJob() {
        int temp = r.nextInt(20);
        for (int i = 0; i <= temp; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((temp + 1) * 100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Executing Thread:" + process.getPid());
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized private boolean sendMessage() {
        boolean response = false;
        try {
            Election.electionLock.lock();
            if (Election.isElectionFlag() && !RunningThread.isMessageFlag(this.process.getPid() - 1) && this.process.priority >= Election.getElectionDetector().getPriority()) {

                for (int i = this.process.getPid() + 1; i <= this.total_processes; i++) {
                    try {
                        Socket electionMessage = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 10000 + i);
                        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "] -> Process[" + i + "]  responded to election message successfully");
                        electionMessage.close();
                        response = true;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "] -> Process[" + i + "] did not respond to election message");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                this.setMessageFlag(true, this.process.getPid() - 1);//My message sending is done
                Election.electionLock.unlock();
                return response;
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            Election.electionLock.unlock();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMessageFlag(int index) {
        return RunningThread.messageFlag[index];
    }

    public static void setMessageFlag(boolean messageFlag, int index) {
        RunningThread.messageFlag[index] = messageFlag;
    }

    synchronized private void serve() {
        try {
            boolean done = false;
            Socket incoming = null;
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(12345);
            Election.setPingFlag(true);
            int temp = this.r.nextInt(5) + 5;// min 5 requests and max 10 requests
            for (int counter = 0; counter < temp; counter++) {
                incoming = s.accept();
                if (Election.isPingFlag()) {
                    System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]:Yes");
                }
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(incoming.getInputStream());
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(), true);
                while (scan.hasNextLine() && !done) {
                    String line = scan.nextLine();
                    if (line.equals("Who is the co-ordinator?")) {
                        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]:-> " + this.process.getPid());
                        out.println(this.process.getPid());
                        out.flush();
                        out.println(this.process.getPriority());
                        out.flush();
                    } else if (line.equals("Resign")) {
                        this.process.setCoOrdinatorFlag(false);
                        out.println("Successfully Resigned");
                        out.flush();
                        incoming.close();
                        s.close();
                        System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]:-> Successfully Resigned");
                        return;
                    } else if (line.equals("Don't Resign")) {
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //after serving 5-10 requests go down for random time
            this.process.setCoOrdinatorFlag(false);
            this.process.setDownflag(true);
            try {
                incoming.close();
                s.close();
                sock[this.process.getPid() - 1].close();
                Thread.sleep(15000);//(this.r.nextInt(10) + 1) * 10000);//going down
                recovery();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sock[this.process.getPid() - 1] = new ServerSocket(10000 + this.process.getPid());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        while (true) {
            if (process.isCoOrdinatorFlag()) {
                //serve other processes
                serve();
            } else {
                while (true) {
                    //Execute some task
                    executeJob();
                    //Ping the co-ordinator
                    pingCoOrdinator();
                    //Do Election
                    if (Election.isElectionFlag()) {
                        if (!sendMessage()) {//elect self as co-ordinator
                            Election.setElectionFlag(false);//Election is Done
                            System.out.println("New Co-Ordinator: Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "]");
                            this.process.setCoOrdinatorFlag(true);
                            for (int i = 0; i < total_processes; i++) {
                                RunningThread.setMessageFlag(false, i);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

package newbully;

public class Process {

    int pid;
    boolean downflag,CoOrdinatorFlag;

    public boolean isCoOrdinatorFlag() {
        return CoOrdinatorFlag;
    }

    public void setCoOrdinatorFlag(boolean isCoOrdinator) {
        this.CoOrdinatorFlag = isCoOrdinator;
    }
    int priority;

    public boolean isDownflag() {
        return downflag;
    }

    public void setDownflag(boolean downflag) {
        this.downflag = downflag;
    }

    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Process() {
    }

    public Process(int pid, int priority) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.downflag = false;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.CoOrdinatorFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error message in both cases is "Address already in use: JVM_Bind".

This message is usually part of a java.net.BindException which is thrown when you try to create/open a Socket and the port is already in use. In this case you are likely trying to open or create the the same socket twice.

This can occur because between opening and closing of the socket an exception stops the socket.close() ever being called. In this case when you create a socket to the election leader, but because the host is "crashed" an exception is thrown and therefore the close() is never called.

I think you need to add the line

electionMessage.close(); to the catch clause of this part of send message.

```
try {
    Socket electionMessage = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 10000 + i);
    System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "] -> Process[" + i + "]  responded to election message successfully");
    electionMessage.close();
    response = true;
} catch (Exception ex) {
//Add close here
    System.out.println("Process[" + this.process.getPid() + "] -> Process[" + i + "] did not respond to election message");
}
```

Also I would recommend adding the close to all other relevant catch clauses, in case it is elsewhere that this is happening and is always good practice to avoid related issues.
I would also recommend specifying clearly which Exceptions you want to catch in each place so that you don't get caught out by other pitfalls.

I hope this is a good starting point.

---

### Edit in response to 1st comment

I think there is a problem with the way you are "locking" your threads. You are relying on a boolean flag to tell you that a particular point in the code has been reached. But the boolean flag is not itself controlled in a synchronized block, nor with any other locks on the code. Thus multiple threads can pass the lock and cause unexpected events, such as multiple attempts to open the same socket.

You are using code with an Object for a lock

```
if (Election.isMessageFlag()) {
    synchronized (Election.lock) {
        Election.lock.wait();
    }
}
Election.setMessageFlag(true);
if (Election.isElectionFlag()) {
   // Do Stuff
   // Open/close Sockets etc
}
Election.setMessageFlag(false);
synchronized (Election.lock) {
    Election.lock.notifyAll();
}
```

That is more than one thread may pass the first if statement before the flag is set (on the next line!) to make subsequent threads wait.

However if you use a ReentrantLock instead you should use code like this:

```
lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
try {
  // Do Stuff
  // OPen CLose Sockets etc
} finally {
  lock.unlock()
}
```

Clearly you may still need to set some flags to say whether or not the election is taking place, but make sure you protect the running code with either real Locks, e.g. ReentrantLock, or within appropriate synchronized blocks.

Hope this helps

Comment: if the socket was not opened why would I need to close() it
I found the reason for the exception
It is happening because if u look closely in output just before the exception message it has elected the co-ordinator 2ce.
Whenever a Thread is elected as co-ordinator it opens a ServerSocket at port 12345.
Since it happened 2ce it might be throwing exception.

But I dont get it... why did it elect the 2ce

Comment: I think their is a problem with the way you are trying to provide mutual exclusion to certain parts of your code. I provide details in the edit above